# nginx Returning 404 After Server Move (AWS)

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

Moved my site to a larger instance size at AWS which allocated me a new private IP and Public DNS value. The Public, elastic IP is the same.

The site loads fine from Apached, but when enabling nginx fastci php-fpm, some old URLs are throwing 404s when accessing the links directly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing can be said about the issue without having details on software configuration, PHP application and its configuration.

Comment: I know I had this same issue the first time I set it up on EC2, but can't remember the fix. It has to do something with the internal (private) ip address and the public one. I was being purposefully vague about the app config as nothing has changed there.

Comment: Well, without knowing about how the application works and other configuration, it is hard to give any answers or guesses where the problem is.